# How to increase plt.title font size?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm using Pythons `matplotlib` and this is my code:

```
  plt.title('Temperature \n Humidity')
```

How can I just increase the font size of temperature instead of both the temperature & the humdity?

This does NOT work:

```
 plt.title('Temperature \n Humidity', fontsize=100)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figtext(.5,.9,'Temperature', fontsize=100, ha='center')
plt.figtext(.5,.8,'Humidity',fontsize=30,ha='center')
plt.show()
```

Probably you want this. You can easily tweak the `fontsize` of both and adjust there placing by changing the first two `figtext` positional parameters.
ha is for [horizontal alignment](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set%5Fhorizontalalignment)

Alternatively,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() # Creates a new figure
fig.suptitle('Temperature', fontsize=50) # Add the text/suptitle to figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # add a subplot to the new figure, 111 means "1x1 grid, first subplot"
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.80) # adjust the placing of subplot, adjust top, bottom, left and right spacing  
ax.set_title('Humidity',fontsize= 30) # title of plot

ax.set_xlabel('xlabel',fontsize = 20) #xlabel
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', fontsize = 20)#ylabel

x = [0,1,2,5,6,7,4,4,7,8]
y = [2,4,6,4,6,7,5,4,5,7]

ax.plot(x,y,'-o') #plotting the data with marker '-o'
ax.axis([0, 10, 0, 10]) #specifying plot axes lengths
plt.show()
```

Output of alternative code:

[image]

PS: if this code give error like `ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file` esp. in `Arch like systems`. In that case, install `tk` using `sudo pacman -S tk` or [Follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504746/importerror-libtk8-6-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direct)

Comment: Hi Meher, what is the .5,.9 ?

Comment: I have specified there. These are positional parameter of the titles. You can say it as padding also. one for the x-axis and one for the y-axis. Just try manipulating them, you will understand; e.g., The text "Humidity" was just below "Temperature" so I place it just below by giving a value to the y-axis position as .8 where as x-axis position parameter is same as that of "Temperature", i.e., .5 .

Comment: Hi Meher, how can i get the figtext to display on top of the graph rather than on the figure

Comment: Sorry to say it may not be possible with `figtext`; except tweaking the font size and positional parameters accordingly. You should have posted some more code with some example data. Now I am posting a different code; but that would be problematic / annoying to you if you are on a project / already plotted the data. See the updated code.

Comment: hi Meher, i got an error that says ax is not defined

Comment: you may have left `fig.add_subplot(111) ` line assignment to `ax`, i.e., `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)`. code is perfectly fine. I have checked it again in python command line now.

Comment: ax is just a variable for the figure object. But anyway good to know it worked.

Answer (score 53):

**fontsize** can be assigned inside dictionary **fontdict** which provides additional parameters fontweight, verticalalignment , horizontalalignment

The below snippet should work

`plt.title('Temperature \n Humidity', fontdict = {'fontsize' : 100})`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  20x simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: I found [this tutorial helpful](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/04/data-visualization-python-matplotlib-seaborn.html)

Answer (score 5):

This has been mostly working for me across recent versions of Matplotlib (currently 2.0.2). It is helpful for generating presentation graphics:

```
def plt_resize_text(labelsize, titlesize):
    ax = plt.subplot()
    for ticklabel in (ax.get_xticklabels()):
        ticklabel.set_fontsize(labelsize)
    for ticklabel in (ax.get_yticklabels()):
        ticklabel.set_fontsize(labelsize)
    ax.xaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(labelsize)
    ax.yaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(labelsize)
    ax.title.set_fontsize(titlesize)
```

The odd for-loop construction seems to be necessary to adjust the size of *each* tic label.
Also, the above function should be called just before the call to `plt.show(block=True)`, otherwise for whatever reason the title size occasionally remains unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using matplotlib to render some plots.

You might want to checkout [Text rendering With LaTeX — Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html)

Here are some lines of code for your case

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.title(r"\begin{center} {\Large Temperature} \par {\large Humidity} \end{center}")
```

[image: plot]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following:
`ax.set_title('This is the title',fontsize=20)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to go into this chart exactly
Universal method:
step one - make a distance between the main title and the chart:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.titlepad'] = 20
```

then insert subtitle by setting coordinates:

```
ax.text(0.3, -0.56, 'subtitle',fontsize=12)
```

[image]