# ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, archlinux

I am trying to add a **GUI** input box and I found out that the way you do that is by using a module called `tkinter`. While I was trying to install it on my arch linux machine through the `ActivePython` package I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

shell returned 1\
```

Comment: _"`import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk`"_ so I guess we at least know what the problem is.

Comment: _"...I tried to fit this into the as least lines as possible..."_  While this may be true that you tried, it does _not_ mean that above post has a code piece that fits the required [mcve]. You need to provide the code part as well to reproduce that error.

Comment: I dont undestand what you mean...

Comment: What produces the above error? `import tkinter` line alone?

Comment: Yup, I just tried to delete everything and i get the same output

Comment: Please provide that as well then. As in I tried `import tkinter` and I got the error : `...`. At which point I think it's a perfect post.

Comment: Alredy found the answer bro...thanks anyways...how do i mark this post as solved now?

Comment: You can mark your own answer, but it may require a certain period of time before you can.

Comment: If you've found the answer, it doesn't necessarily mean your question is garbage now. You can still edit the question for improvement, so that others can easily reach the same information later.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/5459444/7032856

Answer (score 86, accepted):

All you need to do is to install the tkinter package. Now universal precompiled packages such as ActivePython will not work, well at least it didn't work for me. I don't know if this problem occurs in other OSes but I know the solution for Linux: install the Tk package from a repository.

In Arch, Tk is available in the Arch repository. You don't need aur for this, just type on the terminal:

```
sudo pacman -S tk
```

If you are on a Debian, Ubuntu or another Debian-based distro, just type on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install tk
```

On Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install tk
```

Tk is not to be mistaken with python-tk, which is a package for Python 2 (you shouldn't need it unless you are working with legacy code).

Answer (score 10):

Install tk through command line

```
sudo pacman -S tk
sudo apt-get install tk
```

depending on your OS.
It will work.

```
import tk
```

or

```
import turtle  # (turtle uses tk as a dependancy)
```

reproduces the error.

Also doing pip install does not removes the error.
So you must install tk through your package manager like mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

I'm on Manjaro, use Gnome3 on Wayland. After installed `tk` I got an error about Xorg. So I use Google, and found I need to install `python-pygubu` from [Visual editor for creating GUI in Python 3 tkinter](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221077).

And then another error like: [Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2061142). Also found a solution, to install `gtk-engine-murrine` form that link.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to be working with [Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) then the below command will install `tk`.

```
apk add tk
```